# Service not Register After Changing in package name

Tags: android, android-studio

After I Change package name there is an error occur like.

I am tryng to change package name. package name will be change but there is an error that service not register. and my application cant able to run properly. application cant able to destroy launcher activity.

```
06-26 16:45:19.806  27366-27366/my.instaupdate.otr.app.im E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: my.instaupdate.otr.app.im, PID: 27366
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {my.instaupdate.otr.app.im/my.instaupdate.otr.app.im.app.WelcomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: my.instaupdate.cacheword.CacheWordActivityHandler@14403580
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3758)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: my.instaupdate.cacheword.CacheWordActivityHandler@14403580
                at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1033)
                at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1936)
                at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:550)
                at my.instaupdate.otr.app.im.app.WelcomeActivity.onDestroy(WelcomeActivity.java:231)
                at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6132)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1163)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3745)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:148)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1346)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

this error about what???

Comment: check once service packagename in manifest.

Comment: package name is **my.instaupdate.otr.app.im.permission....**

Comment: place your manifest and your activity class also.

Comment: thanks error solved. there is some issue package name in activity file.